# Why is the Hackage Matrix Builder for my package incorrect?

Tags: haskell, hackage

Why is the information [for my package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma-0.1.1.6) in the [Hackage Matrix Builder](https://matrix.hackage.haskell.org/#/package/crypto-enigma) not in sync with my package? The latest state of the matrix shows no compatibility beyond GHC 7.10.3 even though the same revision correctly shows compatibility through at least 8.10 for the same revision.

Why is the Hackage Matrix Builder for my package incorrect? How do I fix it?

Comment: I remember that the matrix build was broken some time ago, and that the packages for the base, etc. did not run either.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh so it's obsolete now? If so is there something similar I could use.

Comment: I think you can queue a new build, or perhaps ask some admin to do that. This is a button at the right side of the matrix. I think I queued one for you with low priority.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In my experience that takes a couple years to have an effect.

Comment: well I tried this once, and it took a couple of hours (~6), but as far as I know they improved the efficiency of the buidling process.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem OK we'll see. Maybe something just glitched. In any case it sounds like nothing I can do much about.

Comment: the build has finished, and it seems that now the extra GHC versions appear on the matrix: https://matrix.hackage.haskell.org/#/package/crypto-enigma

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Seems fine now. I'll accept something like: "Sometimes it just takes a while to clean up" as an answer if you want to provide one.